# No module named '_dbus_bindings' -16.04

Tags: python, bug-reporting, dbus

I've been trying to update python. And every since I can't seem to access "Updates&Software"
I try to run `software-properties-gtk` this error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 29, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import ( 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

list of files under /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus

```
bus.py         exceptions.py                lowlevel.py  service.py
_compat.py     _expat_introspect_parser.py  mainloop     types.py
connection.py  gi_service.py                proxies.py   _version.py
_dbus.py       glib.py                      __pycache__
decorators.py  __init__.py                  server.py
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dbus    
python-dbus is already the newest version (1.2.0-3)
```

Answer (score -1):

this sounds like the same situation we looked at previously, it seems like your system repo got out of wack. can you try running

```
sudo apt dist upgrade
```

if that doesn't work, you might have python 3.5 installed, let's try to uninstall python 3.5 https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=881614

```
sudo apt purge python3.5*
```

install 3.7

```
sudo apt install python3.7
```

see if that get's you out of a bind

Comment: Uninstalling Python3.5* removed most of my system!
You might want to add a warning to your answer Charles :)